# How to get loop variable suffixed in v-text to get the exact key from data?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am not able to print the `i in passengers.count` to `v-text="passengers.details.title_i"`

I tried wrapping it like this `v-text="passengers.details.title_[i]"` but doesn't work.

```html
   <div v-if="_.size(passengers.details) > 0" v-for="i in passengers.count" :key="i" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
     <h4>Passenger <span v-text="i"></span></h4>
     <ul class="list-inline">
       <li><label>Title:</label> <span v-text="passengers.details.title_${i}"></span></li>
       <li><label>First Name:</label> <span v-text="passengers.details.first_name_${i}"></span></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
```

I need `v-text="passengers.details.title_[i]"` to be read as

`v-text="passengers.details.title_1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use square brackets around the whole property name, not just the number on the end.

You could use backticks:

```html
<span v-text="passengers.details[`title_${i}`]"></span>
```

Or just concatenation:

```html
<span v-text="passengers.details['title_' + i]"></span>
```

Not sure why you're using `v-text`, using `{{ ... }}` would seem simpler:

```html
<span>{{ passengers.details[`title_${i}`] }}</span>
```

Comment: Awsome it worked! Thanks for clarifying my issue :)